# PHP: Retrieve the value of a specified key in an array

Tags: php

I have an array labeled `$friendRequest`.
When i do `echo print_r($friendRequest)`, I get

```
Array ( 
    [result] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 11 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

The part that I care about is `[id]=>11`, I want to assign that value to a variable.  So lets say i have variable `$a`, `$a = 11` is what i want. How can I do this?

Comment: `$a = $friendRequest['result'][0]['id']`

Comment: Above (`^`) and why would you `"echo print_r()"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that with a code like this:

```
$a = array['id'];
```

I guess your array is called "$friendrequest" so let's say

```
$a = $friendRequest['result'][0]['id']
echo $a;
```

Comment: No. You cant. It's a multi-dimensional array. I won't downvote this answer because I'm sure you'll fix it.

Comment: I see, OP got updated just after i placed this haha [edit] Updated!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$a = $friendRequest['result'][0]['id']
var_dump($a); //int 11
```